# How fast are spatial queries run using mySQL spatial indexing?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, geospatial

Specifically for the common real world query type with the following inputs:

- Latitude and longitude coordinates
- Radius in meters

If I want to return all the stored points within the radius of the input coordinate, how fast can I expect this to be using mySQL spatial indexing and querying?

How would this query time vary  running on ten thousand, one hundred thousand, and one million stored data points?

Thanks

Comment: On a laptop from the 1990s or a 256-core monster with a terabyte of RAM?

Comment: If you "don't like" the answer, what is your "Plan B"?

Answer (score 0):

Erm, very fast? In theory, its marginally slower than a linear range lookup using a btree index but you're unlikely to notice the difference (of course functionally these are very different and not interchangeable). The time to retrieve a single row based on a geospatial index should increase in the order log(n).

Comment: Thanks for the info. For my reference would it be able to do this type of query on a million data points in a few seconds? less?

Comment: For a query which only needs to examine a few rows, (i.e. the index reduces the number of rows to retrieve from the table from lots to ten or twenty) you should see response times under 50ms